# AZURE CLI FileSystemStorage from Webapp Usage

Tags: azure, powershell, command, command-line-interface

I'm working on a Azure Cli project (can't use Powershell), but i have a problem with one Azure cli command.

This is a good Powershell command :
**Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName  -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/usages -ResourceName "" -ApiVersion 2018-02-01**

I can't do the same with CLI (i can't access to Usage part :
**az resource show --resource-group  --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/usages' --name '' --api-version '2018-02-01'**

=> This command give me the result of the serverfarms information.
[image]

[image]

How access to the usages level to obtain the FileSystemStorage value ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Florent.

Comment: Looks like you skipped part of the path `Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/apps-groupebriand/usages -ResourceName "" -ApiVersion 2018-02-01`

Comment: Hello,I tried lot of things : Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/apps-groupebriand/usages/, Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/apps-groupebriand/usages. all word after Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/apps-groupebriand/ is not used. i can write Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/apps-groupebriand/XXXXX and it works

Comment: May be you could not get that via azure cli.

Comment: Some information are available throught Powershell and not CLI ?

Comment: If you want to get it via powershell, use `Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/usages -ResourceName "<service plan name>" -ApiVersion 2018-02-01` Or you mean you want to get `FileSystemStorage` with powershell?